# google pdf viewer (cant use params in the pdf url)

Tags: google-document-viewer

Im using the google drive viewer to render external urls in my App (with ionic). It's something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer/viewer?url=http://domain.com/pdf_petition.php?param1=a&param2=b">...
```

The question is that google viewer only take the first parameter from the url, ignoring the second parameter.

I've tried parsing the pdf url (like http%3A%2F%2Fdomain%2Fpdf_petition.php%3Fparam1%3Da%26zparam2%3Db ) but the viewer cant load anything.

There is a special form to get parameters in the pdf url ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, just encode `&` (replace with `%26`) That should do the trick.